# Open xml reading incorrect data

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have a problem when reading Excel file with open xml - I want my program to read through all rows and display data. In foreach loop which iterates through rows program gets random number of rows,which is larger than the actual number of rows in excel in which something is written and it results in NullReferenceException. Shouldn't it be that foreach "knows" when to stop?

```
        var sharedStringTable = myWorkbook.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
        var definedNames = myWorkbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.DefinedNames;

        var worksheetPart = myWorkbook.GetWorksheetPartByName("Sheet1");

        SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
        int lala = 1;

        var rows = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>();
        foreach (Row r in rows)
        {
            var val1 = worksheetPart.ReadCellContent(definedNames, sharedStringTable, string.Format("B{0}", lala));
            lala++;
        }
```

Comment: Where is the NRE happening?

Comment: Foreach loop reads the last row in which something is written and in next loop it jumps out(exception is thrown)

Comment: But what line and on what item is the Exception pointing to?

Comment: It is thrown in line which begins with "var val1 = worksheetPart.ReadCe..."

Comment: Where are you referencing `r` within that loop? That's what a foreach is for... A foreach shouldn't just be used as a counter, that's why you are declaring that new variable in `foreach (Row r in rows)`

Comment: I changed excel template and foreach now seems to stop where it is supposed. Hmm, I guess that was excel bug then. Thank you for help!

Comment: No problem! I suppose I'll post that as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't ever referencing r within your loop. A foreach shouldn't just be used as a counter, that's why you are declaring that new variable in `foreach (Row r in rows)`.

Basically, you are looping through your `rows` but making calls to/referencing items which are not a part of `r` (the row you are looping through at the current iteration) in any way.